# Concatenate and pass as parameter in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Need some help with removing default gateway.
For example, there is an IP 192.168.4.15 with default gateway 192.168.4.14. I connect to WLAN with gw 10.0.0.1 and after that I would like do remove previous gw.

```
  IFS='.' read -ra IPARR <<< "$IP"
  Gateway="${IPARR[0]}.${IPARR[1]}.${IPARR[2]}.14"
  ssh blah@$IP '/sbin/route -v del default gw $Gateway;'
  #ssh blah@$IP '/sbin/ip route delete $Gateway dev rndis0;'
  #ssh blah@$IP '/sbin/route -n'
```

Both ways don't work. However, it is possible to remove it if I ssh into machine. My guess is that something wrong with passing $Gateway variable.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Use double quotes around the command like `ssh blah@$IP "/sbin/route -v del default gw $Gateway;"`

Comment: duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/176573/4667

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been said, using single quotes will pass the literal string `$Gateway`, rather than your intended variable value, instead use double quotes

```
ssh blah@$IP "/sbin/route -v del default gw $Gateway;"
```